# ListView with Contextual Action Bar

Tags: java, android, listview, android-actionbar

I have a `ListView` in my activity which is set to `CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE` originally. I supply it the textViewResourceId of `R.id.simple_list_item_1` as I am only displaying single lines of text.

When I long press on an item, I am able to bring up the Contextual Action Bar (CAB) with a delete icon. Deleting the items that would be selected isn't the problem. My problem arises when I need to display which items are actually selected. Because the textViewResourceId is `simple_list_item_1`, this textView doesn't show selected items as it was made for single choice only. Is there a way to change this resourceId at runtime so that the `ListView` can start displaying multiple selections, and then return to single select upon exiting the CAB?

Comment: I guess posting some code will be more easier for others to provide you solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem! I set the textViewResourceId to `simple_list_item_activated_1`, which highlights the selected choice and initialized the ListView in `ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE`. In `onItemClick`, I set the clicked item to unchecked if the choice mode is single. In `onItemLongClick`, I set the choice mode to `ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULIPLE` and opened the Contextual Action Bar (CAB). I handle the menu items of the CAB from the helper method, and when I destroy the action mode, I also set the choice modes back to `ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE`.